# drawImage only works in paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, drawimage

I'm new to graphics in Java and I want to draw an image from my computer. However, the image only shows when I put my code inside the paintComponent. Here's what works:

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("meow.jpg");
    g.drawImage(pic, 100, 100, 350, 300, this);
}
Image [] images;
Image pic;
```

If I put the code in a different method such as:

```
public void drawCat(Graphics g) {
    pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("meow.jpg");
    g.drawImage(pic, 100, 100, 350, 300, this);
}
Image [] images;
Image pic;
```

nothing shows up. I don't see much differences between the two methods, so how can I get my image to draw inside drawCat?

Comment: Call `drawCat` from `paintComponent` (and don't do I/O in the UI thread).

Comment: You can use class [ImageIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) to display an image.